# Убрать локализованную метку [сео]

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Предлагаю убрать (именно удалить/объединить(?)) метку [сео](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%be), являющуюся калькой (причем неверной) с оригинального [seo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) (который желательно писать заглавными буквами, ибо это аббревиатура). В английском языке есть понятие CEO, но оно совсем про другое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объединять не надо, т.к. метка кривая.

Из текущих вопросов я её убрал. Со временем сама пропадёт из списка, если никто использовать не будет.

Comment: Товарищ модератор Вы здесь ?

Comment: @MaximLensky смотря кто спрашивает (¬‿¬ )

Comment: я спрашиваю , в общем  смотри: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1010446/308951  вопрос на мету надо

Comment: @MaximLensky не уверен, что в таком виде он на мете нужен =/ Но может автор уточнит вопрос, посмотрим.

Comment: тут наверно вопрос больше Никаласу будет интересен ... он наверно хочет типа как  у фейсбука или как у вк ...что то типа того